# Springboot application enable one database at a time among mariadb and mongo i.e based on key given in properties file

Tags: mongodb, mariadb

I have configured 2 databases in application.properties file. and want to activate one database at a time based on key given in application.properties.i.e if key is mongo then mongo database(mongotemplate) will configure to perform crud operation else mariadb.

Comment: Please reply asap. its urjent

Comment: This seems like a very strange thing to ask for.  By "database" do you mean "server"?  "Instance" of database engine?  Or "Create Database"?